# Terraform - AWS Multiple subnets issue

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm attempting to deploy multiple ec2 instances, in which each Web Server ec2 instances in different sub-nets and Application Server instance in specific sub-nets.

When using count parameter each webservers get properly deployed in different sub-nets, but application instance get deployed in same sub-net instead of two sub-net which i specified on **"Application resource"** section given below.

How can i specify application server to be created in specific sub-nets which created using count parameter as specified in below  **"Public Subnets Resource"** section.

.

**Variable declaration :**

```
variable "subnet_private_cidr" {
type = "list"
default = ["10.10.1.0/24", "10.10.2.0/24", "10.10.3.0/24", "10.10.4.0/24"]
}
variable "subnet_public_cidr" {
type = "list"
default = ["10.10.0.0/24", "10.10.5.0/24", "10.10.6.0/24", "10.10.7.0/24"] 
}
variable "azs" {
type = "list"
default = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c", "us-east-1d"]
}
```

**Public Subnets Resource :**

```
resource "aws_subnet" "qasubnet_public" {
count = "${length(var.subnet_public_cidr)}"
vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.qa_vpc.id}"
cidr_block = "${element(var.subnet_public_cidr,count.index)}"
availability_zone = "${element(var.azs,count.index)}"
tags {
       Name = "QASUBNET_PUBLIC-${count.index+1}"
}
}
```

**Private Subnets Resource :**

```
resource "aws_subnet" "qasubnet_private" {
count = "${length(var.subnet_private_cidr)}"
vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.qa_vpc.id}"
cidr_block = "${element(var.subnet_private_cidr,count.index)}"
availability_zone = "${element(var.azs,count.index)}"
tags { 
       Name = "QASUBNET_PRIVATE-${count.index+1}"
}
}
```

**Webserver Resource :**

```
resource "aws_instance" "webserver" {
count = "${length(var.subnet_public_cidr)}"
ami = "${var.webserver_ami}"
instance_type = "t2.medium"
vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.webserver.id}"]
key_name = "${var.aws_key_name}"
subnet_id = "${element(aws_subnet.qasubnet_public.*.id,count.index)}"
}
```

**Application Resource :**

```
resource "aws_instance" "appserver" {
count = 2
ami = "${var.appserver_ami}"
instance_type = "t2.medium"
vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.appserver.id}"]
key_name = "${var.aws_key_name}"
subnet_id = "${element(aws_subnet.qasubnet_private.*.id,0)}"
subnet_id = "${element(aws_subnet.qasubnet_private.*.id,1)}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your trying to do in your:

```
  subnet_id              = "${element(aws_subnet.qasubnet_private.*.id,0)}"
  subnet_id              = "${element(aws_subnet.qasubnet_private.*.id,1)}"`
```

in your resource "aws_instance.appserver", it should be just the one **subnet_id** reference:

```
  subnet_id              = "${element(aws_subnet.qasubnet_private.*.id,count.index)}"
```

With a count statement, this will give you one instance per subnet.

Comment: Thanks @James Woolfenden. Yes, i know the code i specified is wrong i am trying to solve that. What i am trying to do in that section is specifying 2 subnet manually. 4 subnet get created dynamically using count parameter in Private Subnets Resource section . If i use subnet_id  you specified then  Aplication server will get created in all 4 subnet but i want it only get created in 2 subnet  .

Comment: @Sreeraju V,  James' solution is what you want to do. If count is 2, then count.index is 0,1. the code will create two app server instances and first one will be in private subnet 0 and second will be private subnet 1. it will not create 4 instances.